# Add a compile flag to a set of files in cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran, fortran90, fortran77, intel-fortran

Many of my files are old legacy fortran and require the `-save` flag (intel) or `-fno-automatic` (gfortran), but new parts of the code have OpenMP directives and specifically need `-auto` (intel) for `-fautomatic` (gfortran). I call the legacy files name.f and the new files name.for (for ease of emacs editing)
So then I set

```
CMAKE_FORTRAN_FLAGS="-O3 -save"
CMAKE_FORTRAN95_FLAGS="-auto"
```

Then in my CMakeLists.txt file I have:

```
FOREACH(f ${for_SOURCES})
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(f_abs_path ${f} ABSOLUTE)
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(f_path ${f} PATH) #DIRECTORY in modern cmake
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(f_base ${f} NAME_WE)
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(f_ext ${f} EXT)
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(f_name ${f} NAME)
  set (f_processed ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${f_path}/${f_base}.f)
  add_custom_target (${f_base} DEPENDS ${f_processed} )
  add_custom_command (OUTPUT ${f_processed} 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${f_abs_path} ${f_processed} 
    DEPENDS ${f_path}/${f_name})
  set_source_files_properties( ${f_processed} PROPERTIES 
     COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_Fortran95_FLAGS})
  LIST(APPEND processed_files ${f_processed})
ENDFOREACH(f ${for_SOURCES})
```

But it not get the flag as shown by a make `VERBOSE=1`. What can I do?

Comment: Why do the OpenMP files need `-fautomatic` or `-auto`? These are normally implied.

Comment: Yes, I am writing fixed format in the .for files. The .for files are renamed to .f files so that is not a problem and the compiler flags explicitly invoke the format type -fixed or -ffixed-format.

Comment: I would also be wary of the -save option in your compiler flags. This will set the default as sharing variables amongst all OpenMP threads. Generally, you want all variables to have private scoping by default in a OpenMP parallel region. This is especially important if your OpenMP parallel region includes called subroutines.

Comment: So I realized my problem is that variables are not passed into subroutines in CMake. I tried to make a more modern version that collects all the source routines and then processes them in the top directory, but I'm still missing something: `make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../)', needed by `sub/saxpy_noomp.f'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @EddieBaron Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: The best way to do this is to bring all the source files the top directory. A not unreasonable way to do it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765296/cmake-collect-and-process-all-source-files-in-top-directory which is based off this example. http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-March/035992.html. In the end I have a working example that can handle multiple compile flags.