# CMake collect and process all source files in top directory

Tags: cmake, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to collect and process all source files in the top directory, to deal with the fact that variables are not passed to sub directories. I have cobbled together the following CMakeLists.txt files:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(main)
enable_language(Fortran)
enable_testing()

set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ifort)
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS " -g -C -fixed")
set (CMAKE_Fortran95_FLAGS " -openmp ")

# function to collect all the sources from sub-directories
# into a single list
function(add_sources)
  get_property(is_defined GLOBAL PROPERTY SRCS_LIST DEFINED)
  if(NOT is_defined)
    define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY SRCS_LIST
      BRIEF_DOCS "List of source files"
      FULL_DOCS "List of source files to be compiled in one library")
  endif()
  # make absolute paths
  set(SRCS)
  foreach(s IN LISTS ARGN)
    if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${s}")
      get_filename_component(s "${s}" ABSOLUTE)
    endif()
    list(APPEND SRCS "${s}")
  endforeach()
  # append to global list
  set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY SRCS_LIST "${SRCS}")
endfunction(add_sources)



add_sources(SRCS main.f95)
add_subdirectory(sub)

# preprocess sources
set(PREP_SRCS)
get_property(SRCS GLOBAL PROPERTY SRCS_LIST)
foreach(s IN LISTS SRCS)
  file(RELATIVE_PATH rs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${s}")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "f95$" "f" o "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${rs}")
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${o}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${s}" "${o}"
    DEPENDS "${s}"
    if(${s} MATCHES "f95$")
      set_source_files_properties( ${o} PROPERTIES 
     COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_Fortran95_FLAGS})
     endif(${s} MATCHES "f95$")
    COMMENT "Creating ${o}"
    VERBATIM
    )
  list(APPEND PREP_SRCS "${o}")
endforeach()

message(${PREP_SRCS})

add_executable(main ${PREP_SRCS})


SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(main PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(main PROPERTIES 
LINK_FLAGS " ")
```

and in sub/

```
 add_sources(SRCS saxpy2.f95 saxpy_noomp.f)
```

which cmakes correctly:

```
[baron@ray:1034]$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.2.7000181
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.2.7000181
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 15.0.1.20141022
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.108/bin/intel64/ifort
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.108/bin/intel64/ifort  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.108/bin/intel64/ifort supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.108/bin/intel64/ifort supports Fortran 90 -- yes
/Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build/SRCS/Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build/main.f/Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build/sub/SRCS/Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build/sub/saxpy2.f/Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build/sub/saxpy_noomp.f
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/baron/teach/comps/ompstuff/new_new_cmake_test/build
[baron@ray:1035]$ make
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../)', needed by `sub/saxpy_noomp.f'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[baron@ray:1036]$
```

but obviously something subtle is missing. TIA

Comment: You output content of `PREP_SRCS` variable. Why do not output of other variables, which you use for create custom command? This is standard debugging process, which you should done before asking on SO. BTW, even using output you currently have, one may found `SRCS` substring in it, which obviousely is not desired. Origin of this string can be found easily: you call `add_sources(SRCS main.f95)`, while `add_sources` function interpret all its arguments as source files. HINT: for output arrays, enclose them into `"`. Such way elements will be delimited by `;`.

Comment: Sorry to offend you that I ask stupid questions, but I am stupid. You are correct, the fix was simply to add_sources(source file list) and that works. now I want to extend it to add a second executable, with different sources, but I can not clear out SRCS. set(SRCS) obviously does not work, unset(SRCS) also does not work.

Comment: As you accumulate all sources in GLOBAL property, you may clear that property when you add executable. So futher executable will see only new sources. You may rewrite your question post for ask about your new problem. (Generally it is recommended to create new question post, but as your original problem was resolved by fixing simple misprint, it has no value for others).

Comment: Thanks set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY SRCS_LIST) and                        set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY SRCS) did the trick. Never underestimate who will stumble onto something useful with a google search. But this is closed.